# Object modified in the function is not being modified outside the function

Tags: javascript, html, object, variables, scope

I'm building a code to parse some JSON details received from the server into a javascript object. The object has many objects inside it.

Then I have another function to create HTML element and apply that object's values (using `for - in` loop) into HTML tags' "`innerHTML`".

I have included the code i use below,

```
// This one is executed on the 'onLoad' event.

function requestDriverListings() {

**//This object stores the received object from server.**

var drivers = {};

// ***This function requests details from the server and the function in the arguments is executed once the details are received.***


sendUserData ({}, "request driver.php", function (request) {
listDrivers(request,drivers); console.log(drivers); displayDrivers(drivers);});

}
```

This one is the function to create a `HTML Element` and stores the received data in it and the use `JSON.parse()` to parse them into a Object.

The driver parameter is the Object passed in the above code.
`request` parameter has no effect on this problem. (It is the `XHR responseText`.)

```
function listDrivers (request,driver) {
    var response = document.createElement("html");
    response.innerHTML = request;
    driver = response.querySelector("#drivers").innerHTML;
    var stripComma = driver.lastIndexOf(",");
    driver = JSON.parse(driver.substring(0,stripComma) +"}");


}
```

Here is the displayDrivers function.

`drivers` Object is passed into `driveParsed`  in the first function.

`requestAPage()` is a function to request the displaying element from the server. the `function` in it's arguments is the function to apply the Objects details into the `HTML innerHTML`.

```
function displayDrivers (driveParsed) {
    var driverElement = document.createElement("div");
    driverElement.id = "driverElement";
    driverElement.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("driverContainer").appendChild(driverElement);

    requestAPage("Drivers.html", "drivers", "driverElement", function() {  selectDrivers();});


    var selectDrivers = function () {

    for (var x=0; x<=Object.keys(driveParsed).length; x++) {
         var driverParsed = driveParsed[x];
         setDriversDetails(driveParsed,x);
         var element = createAElement( "div", {"margin-top": "10px;"});
         element.id = driveParsed.name;
         element.className  = "container border";
         element.innerHTML = driverElement.innerHTML;
         document.getElementById("driverContainer").appendChild(element);

    }

    };


}
```

================================================================

**My problem is this `displayDrivers()` is not getting the modified `drivers` Object.**

Please help me to solve this problem. Sorry for the long description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that inside `listDrivers` you *assign* a new value to the `driver` variable (which is an argument). This means the original variable, `drivers`, that was passed to the function as second argument, is disconnected from the local function variable `driver`: they are now two distinct, unrelated objects.

If you want the `drivers` variable to get a value from calling the function, then let that be the *return* value of the function, so you would call it like this:

```
sendUserData ({}, "request driver.php", function (request) {
    var drivers = listDrivers(request);  // <-----
    console.log(drivers); 
    displayDrivers(drivers);
});
```

Then the `listDrivers` function would look like this:

```
function listDrivers (request) { // <--- only one argument
    // declare new variable:
    var driver = response.querySelector("#drivers").innerHTML;
    // ... rest of your code comes here ...
    // ... and finally:
    return driver; // <---- return it
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can anybody tell me the reason behind my problem?

Comment: As per my knowledge the Objects are passed by reference, so the changes in the value is rendered outside the function. I can't imagine any reason to not happening that here. (although I'm still new to programming) –

Comment: Indeed, objects are passed by reference (because they *are* references), but when you *assign* a new value, you get a new reference. However, you can *mutate* an object that is passed in, for example by setting an object property: `driver.x = 1`. This change will be seen outside of the function. However, variable assignment is not mutation.

Comment: Thank you, did you mean that If I assign that new values to a property of my passed Object?

Comment: Yes, if you assign to a property of the passed object, then you effectively add it to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

@trincot beat me to it and his answer is better. I'll leave this up anyway though.

Try doing this in `requestDriverListings`:

```
function requestDriverListings() {

  var drivers = {};

  sendUserData ({}, "request driver.php", function (request) {
    var updatedDrivers = listDrivers(request,drivers); 
    console.log(drivers); 
    displayDrivers(updatedDrivers);});
}
```

And this in `listDrivers`:

```
function listDrivers (request,driver) {
  var response = document.createElement("html");
  response.innerHTML = request;
  driver = response.querySelector("#drivers").innerHTML;
  var stripComma = driver.lastIndexOf(",");
  driver = JSON.parse(driver.substring(0,stripComma) +"}");
  return driver;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can anybody tell me the reason behind my problem?

Comment: As per my knowledge the Objects are passed by reference, so the changes in the value is rendered outside the function. I can't imagine any reason to not happening that here. (although I'm still new to programming)